# Fixed side nav with reverse nav list, need active/current jquery state reversed

Tags: jquery, scroll, navigation, fixed

I have a fixed navigation set out in a list as below but it rotated to a side menu in CSS.

```
            <ul class="desktop-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#section4" class="scroll">Section 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section3" class="scroll">Section 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section2" class="scroll">Section 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="current">
                    <a href="#section1" class="scroll">Section 1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I basically need my jQuery to reverse the '.current' class from bottom of the list up (removing it from previous li) upon scroll rather than top to bottom which it currently is:

```
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop() + $('.desktop-nav').outerHeight(true);
                $('.desktop-nav li').not('.lastNav').each(function() {
                    var href = $('a', this).attr('href');
                    if(href == '#header-hold') href = 'body';
                    var elementTop = $(href).offset().top - 0;
                    if(windowTop >= (elementTop)){
                        $('.desktop-nav li').removeClass('current');
                        $('a[href^="'+href+'"]').parent().addClass('current');          
                        if(href == 'body') { $('.desktop-nav li:eq(0)').addClass('current'); }  
                    }
                });
            });
```

Any help would be appreciated!